# Display data from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I have messed with this query for 3 days now and no matter what I cannot get the right result. I'm working on a small database for a friend of mine for his mechanic shop.

I got 3 tables `car`, `jobs` and `invoices`. Everything start with "cars" if you add a `car` you get `car_id` for it. Next step would be to add a job to this car. Of course job goes to `jobs` table and also records `car_id`. After the job is done you can create an invoice out of it which goes to `invoices` table and again records `car_id`.

```
cars                   jobs                invoices
=======================================================
cID, make, model  | jID,cID,job1  |  iID,jID,cID,amount
 1   audi  a6     |  1   1  check |   1   1   1   99.99
 2   bmw   750    |  1   2  oil   |   2   2   2   56.97
 3   saab  95     |  3   3  oil   |   3   3   3   30.22
 1   audi  a6     |  4   1  oli   |   4   4   1   22.33
```

Small draft what the tables look like. And the outcome what I'd like to get should look like this:

```
ID     make      model
--------------------------
1.     audi      a6
       Job 1     Invoice 1
       Job 4     Invoice 4
2.     bmw       750
       Job 2     Invoice 2
3.     Saab      95
       Job 3     Invoice 3
```

Basically when I click my client list I get a table rows with clients and underneath client I'd like to print links to jobs and invoices.
Quite long post but I hope you understand what I mean.

I've tried different JOINs, the latest that I tried was

```
SELECT * FROM cars
  RIGHT JOIN jobs ON cars.car_id=jobs.car_id
  RIGHT JOIN invoices ON cars.car_id=invoices.car_id
ORDER BY cars.car_id;
```

It kind a worked but it gave me separate rows for each job with same client info. May I'm printing the result wrong. I just don't know any more. Can anybody offer a solution for this? right SQL command html for printing.

Comment: Your desired output makes little sense in SQL terms. "job x" does not come from a `make` column so shouldn't be printed as such. You can either do a `GROUP BY cars.car_id` and concatenate the different jobs/invoices, or put that logic into your PHP

Comment: link to the table i'm getting now [link](http://www.merrant.eu)

Comment: Yes, I expect every row will have the "make" and "model", then use the server script to lay it out as you depicted.

Comment: i was printig ti like this
<table>
<tr>
<td> php echo reg </td>
...
</tr>
<tr>
<td> php echo job_id</td><td> php echo inv_id</td>
</tr>
</table>
which obviously dont work the way i want.

Comment: GROUP BY worked quite ok. now table shows last job and last invoice. so i'm getting closer. thanks! also changed SQL little bit. new one SELECT * FROM invoices RIGHT JOIN jobs ON invoices.car_id=jobs.car_id GROUP BY invoices.car_id ORDER BY invoices.car_id

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just make it in a single table with fields like this:

```
    id                  car            job            invoices 
===============+===============+==============+==============+
      1        +  fastCar      +    works     +    99.99     + 
               +               +              +              +
               +               +              +              +
```

With statement like this:

```
CREATE TABLE cars (id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT, car text(50) default '', job text(50) default '', invoices int(5) default NULL);
```

Then you can get all car attributes using a query like:

```
SELECT job FROM cars WHERE car='fastCar';
```

and pass desired values with another query to a teble that contains 
details for the job for example, where you can have job id as needed.

Comment: but what if its a return customer? this way won't i get a new row for it?
if its a return customer then i already have his info so i don't have to enter it again, i'll just add anouther job to his "profile" which will be displayed under his info on the client list. or am i missing something here?

Comment: You can use mysql INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE option described here:
[link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) when insert new customer information into the table.

Comment: You can also run INSERT IGNORE to prevent updating fields on duplication, However, it will do that without notice.